# How to spy on bootstrap context beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring.factories to set bootstrap context

org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=sompePackage.MyBootstrapConfiguration

I was following what is mentioned in this link
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html

I noticed 2 things hope you please can help me with

1- I cannot spy on any bean that is created through the bootstrap context, in other words, if I create a bean of type x in MyBootstrapConfiguration, spying on that bean with @SpyBean is not working, I can spy on all other beans but the bootstrap context ones (I am using springboottest)

2- If I inject ApplicationContext somewhere and print all the defined beans, i cannot see the beans that were created in the bootstrap context, in other words, the bean x that is created in MyBootstrapConfig is not there. However, @Autowired is working fine and the bean is injected correctly.

My questions are:
1- How can i spy or mock the bootstrap context beans?
2- If i cannot find these beans in ApplicationContext, where are they?

Thanks,

Comment: A Spring application can have multiple application contexts, organized in a hierarchy. Very likely, the context you injected is not the one that contains your beans.

Comment: @EugenCovaci, Thanks for the answer, i thought that ApplicationContext is the parent of all contexts, how can i inject the other contexts?? can i spy on beans in other contexts?

Answer (score 0):

try to put break point where you are creating your bean and run with debug mode, then you will find out whether your bean is created or not

Comment: The bean is getting created, there is no issue with that, the problem is spying on that bean and getting the bean using ApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own context for the test scope you are trying to run:

This would look something like:

```
public class TestApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
private static ApplicationContext context;
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) throws 
  BeansException {
    TestApplicationContext.context = context;
}

public static Object getBean(final String beanName) {
    return context.getBean(beanName);
   }
}
```

Then you can create a bean for the context in a @Configuration annotated class.

```
@Bean
public TestApplicationContext testApplicationContext() {
    return new TestApplicationContext();
}
```

Then you can easily reference whatever bean you need by simply:

```
 TestApplicationContext.getBean("someBean");
```

Comment: Thanks Amos, why would i define a new test context? i am using SpringBootTest to initialise the context, i am not looking to change that, the context is initialised correctly. The issue is simply that i cannot spy on the bean that is initialised in Bootstrap context

Comment: The reason you cannot spy on the bean is because of what? Can you share some error you are getting?

Comment: No error, when i spy on the bean and change the behaviour of a method (i.e. Mockito.doReturn("Something").when(bean).someFunction()) the method is not getting invoked, the actual bean method is getting invoked instead, i can spy on any other bean but the beans that are created in the bootstrap context

Comment: 1- I cannot spy on any bean that is created through the bootstrap context, in other words, if I create a bean of type x in MyBootstrapConfiguration, spying on that bean with @SpyBean is not working, I can spy on all other beans but the bootstrap context ones (I am using springboottest)

Can you share the code of the `MyBootstrapConfiguration.java` ?

Comment: It is a normal spring configuration class
@ Configuration
public class MyBootstrapConfiguration {

    @ Bean
    public  MyClass myclass() {
      return new MyClass();
    }
}

Comment: If this is a test configuration class, in order to access beans already initialized in your application, I would extend the application's configuration class instead of creating the beans all over again. try that and let me know.

Comment: This is not a test configuration class, this is application Bootstrap configuration.

Comment: is it annotated with `@Configuration `?

Comment: Sure mate, the configuration is working fine, do you know how to get the list of Bootstrap context beans?

Comment: I dont think you can get a List , I know its possible to reference the application context.
You could either inject/autowire the context like so.
`  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext appContext;`

or from the class you could implement `ApplicationContextAware `.

see http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html